# C++ не правильная JPEG библиотека

Tags: c++, linux, qt

Пытаюсь с помощью Qt 5.9.2 под OpenSuse, скомпилировать два приложения. Первая компилируется без проблем и запускается. Второе приложение с тем же кодом, указывает на ошибку `Wrong JPEG library version: library is 62, caller expects 80` при запуске.

Comment: А если дополнительно установить и версию 80? Речь о libjpeg62-dev и libjpeg80-dev? Кстати, GTK+ FR установлена?

Comment: @ViktorTomilov Не стесняйтесь, пишите ответ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Все же не уверен, что ответ будет корректен, поскольку под OpenSUSE никогда не работал. А вот под *Ubuntu сталкивался несколько раз при использовании libjpeg. Почти всегда помогало:

```
sudo apt-get install libjpegXX-dev , где XX - номер необходимой версии
```

т.е. установка необходимой версии библиотеки. А в одном случае - не помогло. Провозились долго, проблему, в итоге, решили, но 100% понятно не было, как именно. Грешу на GTK+ framework, после удаления которого всё заработало, но так ли это точно, - не знаю.

Comment: Благодарю, попробую

Comment: То же самое под Edubuntu было, только версии, ЕМНИП, 80 и 90. Действительно, установка дополнительно версии библиотеки решает проблему.

Comment: Попробовал, проблема так и осталась. Вот скриншот установленых версий http://prntscr.com/hxz09p . Нужно ли в .pro Файл добавлять LIB? И все же странно, почему первое работает, а второе с таким же кодом нет